# C++ MapType::iterator using updated value

Tags: c++, dictionary

In my C++ code, I access a map through iterator. Update the map if necessary and re-assign it to class variable. In proceeding statements, I want to use updated map value again. Should I load the map again, refresh the iterator? etc. e.g. the map is:

```
MapType tbl = device->trust();
MapType::iterator iter_trust = tbl.begin();
tbl.insert(std::pair<int, double> (node->getId().id(), 0.1));
```

to execute the following on updated value, what should I do?

```
iter_trust = tbl.find(node->getId().id());
```

Comment: What is your question? Whether the iterator is invalidated? All the iterator invalidation rules are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules).

Comment: BTW, your `tbl` is a _copy_ of the original map. Did you want that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MapType tbl = device->trust();
MapType::iterator iter_trust = tbl.find(node->getId().id());

if (iter_trust == tbl.end()) {
   tbl.insert(std::make_pair(node->getId().id(), 0.1));
   iter_trust = tbl.find(node->getId().id());
}
else {
   tbl[node->getId().id()] = 0.1;
}
```

So you'll be sure you upgrade.

Comment: thanks, of course the map is updated. and i would not necessarily be using the last inserted pair in next line. should i reload the map and refresh the iterator?

Comment: OK, I edited my code (add line 5) for update the iterator value.

Comment: Sorry Kashif, I didn't read your real cuestion. No, you shouldn't update the map or the iterator.

Comment: OK, that was obvious, just wanted to make sure... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`std::map::insert` returns an iterator to the newly inserted element. If your `MapType` is some typedef to a `std::map`, you can do

```
std::pair<MapType::iterator, bool> result = tbl.insert(std::make_pair(node->getId().id(), 0.1));
MapType::iterator iter_trust = result.first;
```

and go on.

Btw, note the use of `std::make_pair`, which is usually simpler than using the `pair` constructor directly.

Also, note that `map::insert` returns a *pair* of an iterator and a boolean. The iterator gives you the position of the inserted object, the boolean indicates if the insertion was successful (i.e. the key didn't previously exist in the map)

Comment: thanks, but the map is updated. and i would not necessarily be using the last inserted pair in next line. should i reload the map and refresh the iterator?